# Share variables between 2 structs

Tags: rust, reference, immutability, ownership, borrowing

I am new to Rust and wanted to share memory between variables. I am getting an error regarding references

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct File {
  file_name: String,
  max_value: Vec<f32>,
}

struct FileHolder<'a> {
  file_holder_name: String,
  first_value: HashMap<String, &'a f32>,
  last_value: HashMap<String, &'a f32>,
}

fn get_file() -> File {
  let x = vec![1f32, 2f32, 3f32, 4f32, 5f32];
  let file = File { file_name: String::from("F1"), max_value: x };
  file
}

fn get_files() -> Vec<File> {
  let file1 = get_file();
  let file2 = get_file();
  let file3 = get_file();
  let file4 = get_file();
  let files = vec![file1, file2, file3, file4];
  files
}

fn transfer_to_holder(files: &Vec<File>) -> HashMap<usize, FileHolder> {

  let mut file_holders = HashMap::new();

  for i in 0..3 {
    let mut file_holder = FileHolder {
      file_holder_name: String::from("FH1"),
      first_value: HashMap::new(),
      last_value: HashMap::new()
    };
    file_holders.insert(i,file_holder);
  }
  
  files.iter().map(|file| {
    file_holders.iter_mut().map(|(sensor_index, file_holder_temp)| {
      file_holder_temp.first_value.insert(file.file_name.to_string(), &file.max_value[0]);
      file_holder_temp.last_value.insert(file.file_name.to_string(), &file.max_value[4]);
    })
  });
      
  
//   for file in files {
//     let i = 0;
//     let mut file_holder_temp = file_holders.get_mut(&i).unwrap();
//     file_holder_temp.first_value.insert(file.file_name.to_string(), &file.max_value[0]);
//     file_holder_temp.first_value.insert(file.file_name.to_string(), &file.max_value[4]);
//   }
  file_holders
}

fn main() {
  let files = get_files();
  let file_holder = transfer_to_holder(&files);
}
```

Update: Old Code with errors:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

Struct File {
  file_name: String,
  value: Vec<f32>
}

Struct FileHolder {
  file_holder_name:String,
  first_value: HashMap<String, &f32>,
  last_value: HashMap<String, &f32>
}

fn get_file()->File {
  let x = [1,2,3,4,5];
  let file = File { file_name: String::from("F1"), value: x };
  return file;
}

fn get_files() -> Vec<File> {
  let file1 = get_file();
  let file2 = get_file();
  let file3 = get_file();
  let file4 = get_file();
  let files = Vec[file1, file2, file3, file4];
  return files;
}

fn trasfer_to_holder(files: &Vec<File>) -> FileHolder {
  let file_holder = FileHolder {
    file_holder_name: String::from("FH1"),
    first_value: HashMap::new(),
    last_value: HashMap::new()
  }
  for file in Files {
    file_holder.first_value.insert(file.file_name, &file.value[0]);
    file_holder.last_value.insert(file.file_name, &file.value[4]);
  }
  return file_holder;
}

fn main() {
  let files = get_files();
  let file_holder = trasfer_to_holder(&files);
}
```

Below is the error:

```
cannot borrow `file_holder.first_value` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
```

In this example, I have only 5 files; However, in my real case, I have around 150000 files. If I store 150000 `first_value` and 150000 `last_value` again in `FileHolder`, it is waste of resource. Hence, it would be nice if I refer to the first struct's reference. I have tried multiple things; Played with lifetime but it is difficult to understand for a beginner.

Note: The files and `file_holder` will never be changed once created; There might be some error in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you provided has bunch of invalid syntax and at least a dozen compile errors in it. After cleaning it up I was able to compile the example without any issues:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct File {
  file_name: String,
  max_value: Vec<f32>,
}

struct FileHolder<'a> {
  file_holder_name: String,
  first_value: HashMap<String, &'a f32>,
  last_value: HashMap<String, &'a f32>,
}

fn get_file() -> File {
  let x = vec![1f32, 2f32, 3f32, 4f32, 5f32];
  let file = File { file_name: String::from("F1"), max_value: x };
  file
}

fn get_files() -> Vec<File> {
  let file1 = get_file();
  let file2 = get_file();
  let file3 = get_file();
  let file4 = get_file();
  let files = vec![file1, file2, file3, file4];
  files
}

fn transfer_to_holder(files: &[File]) -> FileHolder {
  let mut file_holder = FileHolder {
    file_holder_name: String::from("FH1"),
    first_value: HashMap::new(),
    last_value: HashMap::new()
  };
  for file in files {
    file_holder.first_value.insert(file.file_name.to_string(), &file.max_value[0]);
    file_holder.first_value.insert(file.file_name.to_string(), &file.max_value[4]);
  }
  file_holder
}

fn main() {
  let files = get_files();
  let file_holder = transfer_to_holder(&files);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=710f24161fe860d0f1c1ca4274eca296)

Also, what you're trying to do to "save space" is actually counter-productive, since on all systems an `&f32` is as big if not twice as big as an `f32`. In the playground environment an `&f32` is indeed twice as big as an `f32`:

```
fn main() {
  dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<f32>()); // prints "4" bytes
  dbg!(std::mem::size_of::<&f32>()); // prints "8" bytes
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d3b7ed72c6d23a6b57081eca14b2b7f)

Therefore, you can simultaneously save space, simplify your code, get rid of the references and lifetime annotations, and just go with this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct File {
  file_name: String,
  max_value: Vec<f32>,
}

struct FileHolder {
  file_holder_name: String,
  first_value: HashMap<String, f32>,
  last_value: HashMap<String, f32>,
}

fn get_file() -> File {
  let x = vec![1f32, 2f32, 3f32, 4f32, 5f32];
  let file = File { file_name: String::from("F1"), max_value: x };
  file
}

fn get_files() -> Vec<File> {
  let file1 = get_file();
  let file2 = get_file();
  let file3 = get_file();
  let file4 = get_file();
  let files = vec![file1, file2, file3, file4];
  files
}

fn transfer_to_holder(files: &[File]) -> FileHolder {
  let mut file_holder = FileHolder {
    file_holder_name: String::from("FH1"),
    first_value: HashMap::new(),
    last_value: HashMap::new()
  };
  for file in files {
    file_holder.first_value.insert(file.file_name.to_string(), file.max_value[0]);
    file_holder.first_value.insert(file.file_name.to_string(), file.max_value[4]);
  }
  file_holder
}

fn main() {
  let files = get_files();
  let file_holder = transfer_to_holder(&files);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9648d71ce8e5130875e27b13de44ea2a)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Sorry for the errors, I didnt know about the playground. Will use next time. Anyway, the problem I was facing is due to the iter step and Hashmap. I have edited the question

Comment: Regarding your memory, does this means I should not use &f32 for memory optimisation compared to f32? Does this apply to all types? As per your sample, we are storing the values again. If have around 1500000 data, it will be stored twice

Comment: You can check the size of some type `T` with `std::mem::size_of::<T>()` and pick whatever is smallest for your use-case.

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it. Had to use foreach and not map. Thanks a lot for your help. One quick question with your suggestion - I have a vector of size [150000,1000] - The type is Vec<Vec<f32>>. If I have to assign that to file_holder, then I have to do clone(). Is this the right way in regards with performance?

Comment: With the above approach I am getting memory error. Is it possible to forget or deref once the Vec is assigned to FileHolder?